# Flow how to deduced for recursive function type?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype

I wrote a function like this:

```
const andThen = it => then => then === undefined ? it : andThen(it/* == null ? it : */ && then(it));
```

And hope it works like the null-safe  sugar of other language, such as `?.let` of kotlin:

```
o?.let { fn(it.a) }.?let { gn(it.b) }?.let { hn(it.c) }
```

However, if I use this function, I could not got a friendly IDE type tips:

```
const r = andThen(1)(it => it + 1)(it => it * 2)(); // expected `number`, but got `any`.
```

So I want to add a `flow` defination for it like this:

```
// try to typed `andThen`:
type AndThen<It> = (thenFn?: <Then>(it: It) => Then) => It | AndThen<Then>/* AndThen<Then, any> //how to define that? */;
```

But it not works that `flow` seems failed to deduced the type of the recursive function.

```
const ok = (() => {
    const fn = (it: 1): AndThen<1> => thenFn => thenFn === undefined ? it : andThen(it && thenFn(it));
    const r = fn(1);
    const rr = r(() => 2); // expected: `1 | AndThen<2>`, got `any`.
    // const rrParam = (_it: 1) => 2; const rr = r(rrParam); // not work too.
    return rr() === 2;
})();
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Can you try something like this: `type IInnerFn = (fn?: Function) => Function`. Not adding as an answer as it is not very specific and does not justifies inner levels

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, but I'm not sure did I understand your means, I have a try to use Function as the type of the thenFn?, but still not work:

``` javascript

    type AndThen<It> = (thenFn?: Function) => It | AndThen<Then>;
    const fn: AndThen<1> = () => { };
    const ff = fn(_i => 2); // still saw `AndThen<any> | 1`, expected `AndThen<2> | 1`

```